# Importing/converting python scripts as colab notebook

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to explore and edit my .py files (python scripts) in the form of colab notebook. I already the uploaded my files in google drive and mounted in the environment. I can edit the file in the right pane but I want to open it as a notebook. I search the web but I couldn't find any solution for that. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You need to upload your code as a `.ipynb` in order for colab to open it as a notebook or create a new colaboratory in your drive and post your code to it

EDIT:
Alternatively you could create a Colaboratory and import your `.py` like this:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("test1.moduleName", "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/test1.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
foo.MyClass()
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. For the first suggestion, I exported my python script as .ipynb from spyder. but trying upload in colab. I got an error. What this problem may be?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is : JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your file is `script.py`. You can use `%%writefile script.py` to edit your `script.py` inside the cell of jupyter notebook.

```
%writefile [-a] filename

Write the contents of the cell to a file.

The file will be overwritten unless the -a (--append) flag is specified.

positional arguments:
  filename      file to write

optional arguments:
  -a, --append  Append contents of the cell to an existing file. The file will
                be created if it does not exist.
```

To read it, use `!cat`.

`!cat script.py`

Comment: and what about colab notebook?

Comment: @dtr43 should work as well.